# Selenium won't find my element by class name (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

Fist of all here is the picture of the HTML code:
[image: HTML]

This is the element I tried to access:
[image: Class]

I tried: `driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium market_commodity_buy_button")`

... but it threw up an error.
[image: Error Code]

I would be glad for any help! 
Regards
-Eirik

Comment: It would be useful if you provided us with the link to that site and your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Selenium, **class name** do not have support for **spaces**. Please remove **spaces** and put `.` instead to make a `css_selector`.

Instead of

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium market_commodity_buy_button")
```

do this :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn_green_white_innerfade.btn_medium.market_commodity_buy_button")
```

Comment: Also, your application is angular based, please put some delays or webdrivewait to let the element rendered properly and then try to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Compound class names are not permitted in Selenium. Locates elements whose class name contains the search value. i.e. you won't be able to pass multiple class names. If you pass multiple class names then you will get `compound class name exception`.

**Wrong way**:

`By.className("alert alert-class")`

**Right way**:

`By.className("alert.alert-class")`